# CSS custom cursor image becomes "wait" after window loses focus

Tags: css, cursor

I am using an image for the CSS cursor, but when the browser window is lost focus (Alt + Tab), then when I focus the browser window the cursor becomes "wait". Only if the cursor is changed will it work normally. I use Google Chrome.

```css
html {
    cursor: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAXUlEQVQ4T63TQQ4AIQgDwPL/R9foqolxQUC5cOpcKAKA+Eb6Dq0aIkmItHwYmUBLJ5AFyCAbEEV+gQiiAl7EBDzIETghLsBC3ICGWGfUKr209W2RrqqcCY/vu3rnAho0OhEpzH5zAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"), auto;
}
```

Comment: I am struggling to understand the issue. It works fine on my end: When the browser is focused and I am within your snippet it changes my cursor accordingly.

Comment: When the window loses focus then windows should take back its cursor, so I think it's normal

Comment: I just checked on another computer and it does not have this error